# Rendering event data with fullcalendar in Zend Framework

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, fullcalendar

I am incorporating jquery's fullcalendar into my ZF application. I can get the calendar to show up in my view, but as soon as I add a JSON URL to the events parameter of fullcalendar and try to send it my event data, all that happens in the JSON string is output to the browser.

Here's the relevant code in my controller:

```
$sfaCalendar = new Model_Exchange();
$sfaCalendar->getCalendarEntries($startDateTime,$endDateTime,'Calendar');
$this->_helper->json($sfaCalendar->data);
```

Here's my view script:

```
<?php
$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/styles/module/urpower/sfa/fullcalendar.css');
$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/styles/module/urpower/sfa/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css');
$this->headScript()->prependScript(
"   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 
            header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        events: '/urpower/sfa/calendar',        
        theme: true,
        });
    });
");

$this->headScript()->appendFile('/scripts/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js');

?>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

The URL in my events parameter is the path to the controller where I create the JSON encoded data.

I've checked the validity of my JSON string and it looks fine. Any ideas why fullcalendar isn't grabbing my data and putting it into the calendar?

Here's my JSON:

```
[
   {
      "title":"Add notes to Innotas notes",
      "start":"2012-01-02T16:30:00Z"
   },
   {
      "title":"Test appointment #1",
      "start":"2012-01-03T21:00:00Z"
   },
   {
      "title":"Test appointment #2",
      "start":"2012-01-03T22:00:00Z"
   },
   {
      "title":"Test appointment #3",
      "start":"2012-01-03T22:30:00Z"
   },
   {
      "title":"Add notes to Innotas notes",
      "start":"2012-01-09T16:30:00Z"
   },
   {
      "title":"Add notes to Innotas notes",
      "start":"2012-01-16T16:30:00Z"
   },
   {
      "title":"SFA Phase 2 - status, testing, etc.",
      "start":"2012-01-19T18:30:00Z"
   },
   {
      "title":"Add notes to Innotas notes",
      "start":"2012-01-23T16:30:00Z"
   },
   {
      "title":"RLK Integration",
      "start":"2012-01-23T17:00:00Z"
   },
   {
      "title":"FW: Quarterly Employee Gathering",
      "start":"2012-01-27T17:30:00Z"
   },
   {
      "title":"Meeting with KAREN DUFFY X423  ALT # DI\/PUMPKIN RIDGE GOLF CLUB",
      "start":"2012-01-30T14:15:00Z"
   },
   {
      "title":"Add notes to Innotas notes",
      "start":"2012-01-30T16:30:00Z"
   }
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any JS errors? I think you should use `prependFile()` for the `fullcalendar.min.js` so it is included before your script block

Comment: Phil, no, there are no JS errors, just the JSON string spit out to the browser. I also tried changing the min.js to use a prepend file, and no change. I'm really starting to think that I'm not even making it out of the controller, that as soon as `$this->_helper->json($sfaCalendar->data);` is executed, the script dies. Using developer's tool bar, when I try to view JS from the page that shows my JSON string, I don't see any of my calendar code, in fact, no JS at all. If I comment out the helper line in my controller, I get to the calendar but without any data!

Comment: @phil found the probable answer.

Comment: maybe you didn't post it but I don't see where you are returning your json data to the view. maybe this change? $this->view->json = $this->_helper->json($sfaCalendar->data);  would send the json back to the view. although for this use of a model you might consider a view helper as opposed to a controller.

Answer (score 1):

I found your problem, you are using the ***action helper*** version of the json helper which disables the **viewrenderer**.

> **24.8.4.5. JSON**
>
> The JSON action helper does several things:
>
> Disables layouts if currently enabled.
>
> Optionally, an array of options to pass as the second argument to
>   Zend_Json::encode(). This array of options allows enabling layouts and
>   encoding using Zend_Json_Expr.
>
> $this->_helper->json($data, array('enableJsonExprFinder' => true));
>
> ***Disables the ViewRenderer if currently enabled.***
>
> Sets the 'Content-Type' response header to 'application/json'.
>
> By default, immediately returns the response, without waiting for the
>   action to finish execution.

If you execute
 `$this->_helper->json($data, true);` *(where true = keep layouts)*
 you'll get the viewRenderer back, as enabling ***keeplayouts => true*** calls the view helper json:

```
//excerpt from:Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Json
public function encodeJson($data, $keepLayouts = false)
    {
        /**
         * @see Zend_View_Helper_Json
         */
        require_once 'Zend/View/Helper/Json.php';
        $jsonHelper = new Zend_View_Helper_Json();
        $data = $jsonHelper->json($data, $keepLayouts);

        if (!$keepLayouts) {
            /**
             * @see Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker
             */
            require_once 'Zend/Controller/Action/HelperBroker.php';
            Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer')->setNoRender(true);
        }

        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: This definitely looks like the right direction, but simply adding the "true" parameter to the helper call did not change anything. I'm going to keep working on this angle, however.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally got this to work (with a coworker's help, as well as digesting some of the ideas here.)

My calendar controller action is not where I should be using the JSON helper. This action just sets the view, where my fullcalendar JS resides. I created another action in the same controller, named calendarevents, and moved the code to retrieve the event data from my model here. Then I execute JSON helper command which sends the formatted data to the browser.

Then, in my calendar view, I changed the event source URL to point to the new calendarevents action, and badda bing, my event data is showing up in my calendar!

Seems to make a lot of sense now, but you know what they say about hind sight!